# Need to install older version of MySQL on Mac El Capitan

Tags: mysql, macos, installation

I want to install an older version of MySQL on a Mac with El Captan (10.11) and I can't find one!

If you go to the site https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/ you can download the latest version for recent versions of OS X or click the link for older versions - which don't seem to give OS X as an option!!

Very frustrating!

I dont wish to upgrade the OS X version to a later version (I lose other things) but I want MySQL and the latest one isn't fully compatible with El Capitan - I've tried it, installed and I get errors about incompatibilities.

Can anyone advise on how I can get a working MySQL on El Capitan?

Many thanks

Dave S

Answer (score 0):

It took me a few hours to figure this out today. The latest version of MySQL that you can easily run on OS X 10.11 (El Capitan) is 5.6, because 5.7 introduces a dependency on clock_gettime, which Apple didn't add until OS X 10.12. You can try downloading and compiling the generic 5.6 source code, but it is *much easier* to install it using Homebrew. The tricky thing though is that Homebrew has disabled 5.6 for lack of "upstream support". So you first have to reenable it by per [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73586208/can-you-install-disabled-homebrew-packages/73595534), then install it.

```
brew edit mysql@5.6
brew install mysql@5.6
```

This worked fine for me today on a MacMini (Late 2014) running OS X El Capitan (version 10.11.6).