# Can you install disabled Homebrew packages?

Tags: maven, homebrew

```
> brew install maven@3.5
Error: maven@3.5 has been disabled because it is not maintained upstream!
```

I don't *want* to have to install Maven 3.5, but I *need* to install Maven 3.5. Can I force Homebrew to install this package it clearly knows about?

Comment: You can add Maven Wrapper to your project, and specify the [Maven version used by Maven Wrapper](https://maven.apache.org/wrapper/#using-a-different-version-of-maven).

Comment: Why do you need such an old version of Maven.. use most recent one... Or if you need to stuck download it manually https://dlcdn.apache.org/maven/maven-3/

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You can edit the formula with:

```
brew edit maven@3.5
```

Remove the line:

```
disable! date: "2022-07-31", because: :unmaintained
```

And install it with:

```
HOMEBREW_NO_INSTALL_FROM_API=1 brew install maven@3.5
```

Comment: this wont work unless you set environment variable HOMEBREW_NO_INSTALL_FROM_API=1 before invoking brew install

Answer (score 5):

After using `brew edit [formula]` to remove the `disable` line, you can install the formula with

```
HOMEBREW_NO_INSTALL_FROM_API=1 brew install [formula]
```

This is mentioned in https://docs.brew.sh/FAQ#can-i-edit-formulae-myself.
`Homebrew 4.0.17-67-gfff93a8` here.

Comment: Wonderful, the answer above didn't work without this flag (Apple M1)

Answer (score 2):

Slight tweak on the other answer to include `HOMEBREW_NO_INSTALL_FROM_API=1`, without this brew will use the API formula file (not your edited one)

Edit the formula with:

```
brew edit maven@3.5
```

Remove the line:

```
disable! date: "2022-07-31", because: :unmaintained
```

And install it with:

```
HOMEBREW_NO_INSTALL_FROM_API=1 brew install maven@3.5
```